# PHP and sanitizing strings for use in dynamicly created DB2 queries

Tags: db2, php, ibm-midrange, sql-injection

I'm relatively new to DB2 for IBMi and am wondering the methods of how to properly cleanse data for a dynamically generated query in PHP.

For example if writing a PHP class which handles all database interactions one would have to pass table names and such, some of which cannot be passed in using `db2_bind_param()`.  Does `db2_prepare()` cleanse the structured query on its own?  Or is it possible a malformed query can be "executed" within a `db2_prepare()` call? I know there is `db2_execute()` but the db is doing something in `db2_prepare()` and I'm not sure what (just syntax validation?).

I know if the passed values are in no way effected by the result of user input there shouldn't be much of an issue, but if one wanted to cleanse data before using it in a query (without using `db2_prepare()/db2_execute()`) what is the checklist for db2?  The only thing I can find is to escape single quotes by prefixing them with another single quote.  Is that really all there is to watch out for?

Comment: To clarify the question, you aren't looking to cleanse DB2 data, you are looking to do something to the user input that you will use to dynamically create an SQL statement.  Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no magic "cleansing" happening when you call `db2_prepare()` -- it will simply attempt to compile the string you pass as a single SQL statement. If it is not a valid DB2 SQL statement, the error will be returned. Same with `db2_exec()`, only it will do in one call what `db2_prepare()` and `db2_execute()` do separately.

EDIT (to address further questions from the OP).

Execution of every SQL statement has three stages:

1. Compilation (or preparation), when the statement is parsed, syntactically and semantically analyzed, the user's privileges are determined, and the statement execution plan is created.
2. Parameter binding -- an optional step that is only necessary when the statement contains parameter markers. At this stage each parameter data type is verified to match what the statement text expects based on the preparation.
3. Execution proper, when the query plan generated at step 1 is performed by the database engine, optionally using the parameter (variable) values provided at step 2. The statement results, if any, are then returned to the client.

`db2_prepare()`, `db2_bind_param()`, and `db2_execute()` correspond to steps 1, 2 and 3 respectively. `db2_exec()` combines steps 1 and 3, skipping step 2 and assuming the absence of parameter markers.

Now, speaking about parameter safety, the binding step ensures that the supplied parameter values correspond to the expected data type constraints. For example, in the query containing something like `...WHERE MyIntCol = ?`, if I attempt to bind a character value to that parameter it will generate an error.

If instead I were to use `db2_exec()` and compose a statement like so:

```
$stmt = "SELECT * FROM MyTab WHERE MyIntCol=" . $parm
```

I could easily pass something like `"0 or 1=1"` as the value of `$parm`, which would produce a perfectly valid SQL statement that only then will be successfully parsed, prepared and executed by `db2_exec()`.

Comment: Most sources suggest using `db2_prepare()` with `db2_execute()` over `db2_exec()` as a means of preventing SQL injection attacks including php.net http://php.net/manual/en/function.db2-exec.php .  Are you saying they are incorrect in saying this?

Comment: No, @mustaccio is not suggesting that, rather pointing out that `db2_exec()` causes a prepare to occur implicitly.

Comment: So what does `db2_prepare()` and `db2_execute()` do behind the scenes which `db2_exec()` doesn't?  Why is it considered "safer" to use the former over the latter?  I'm trying to figure out the filtering steps taken in `db2_prepare()` and `db2_execute()` so I can recreate the same filtering functionality without actually using them.

Comment: prepare() uses parameter markers.  exec() treats a string as an SQL statement.  I'm not sure I'd call that filtering or sanitizing, but parameter markers stop injection attacks because execute() won't treat the injected SQL like SQL - it will treat it like a parameter value.

Comment: Thank you @mustaccio for the further clarification.  What if a variable was to be used as the table name in the from clause though?  `db2_bind_param()` cannot be used in that scenario, How would one sanitize data for this use?  For example: `$VAR = "SENSITIVE_TABLE WHERE RANDOMCOL = ?--";
$query = "SELECT * FROM ".$VAR." WHERE COL1 = ?";

$VAR2 = "SENSITIVE_TABLE WHERE RANDOMCOL <> ?--";
$query2 = "SELECT * FROM ".$VAR2." WHERE COL1 = ?";`.  I know user data should not be used to generate dynamic queries, but I want to have safeguards against it just in case someone slips up.

Comment: Is all there is to it simply escaping single quotes with another single quote and additional situation specific conditionals such as searching for "where" or other SQL keywords in `$VAR` or `$VAR2` in the example above?  I say situation specific because if I can expect a table name "whereToGo" I obviously can't search for "where" and then throw an error.  I guess one universal string to search for is for a comment "--" which would cripple most SQL injection attempts.  Are these assumptions correct?

Comment: Unless you write your own fully fledged SQL parser, I doubt you can achieve what you think you want.